# Delete empty line in glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I created a glossary (called "Symbolverzeichnis") and split it up in two columns using mcolalttree. My problem is the empty line at the beginning of the left column. Does anyone know how to get rid of it? 
Thank you very much in advance :)

Here's my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublesided,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nopostdot,acronyms]{glossaries} %,toc
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} 

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{B}{name={$B$},description={Magnetische Flussdichte}}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},description={Magnetisierung}}
\newglossaryentry{T}{name={$T$},description={Temperatur}}
\newglossaryentry{g}{name={$g$},description={g-Faktor (Landé-Faktor)}}
\newglossaryentry{H}{name={$H$},description={Magnetische Feldstärke}}
\glssetwidest{M   }


\begin{document}
    \printnoidxglossary[type=main,style=mcolalttree,nonumberlist,title={Symbolverzeichnis}]

    \newpage
    \gls{B}, \gls{M}, \gls{T}, \gls{g}, \gls{H}

\end{document}
```

And the Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Did you try it without the `\newpage` command? I don't see any need for it and it's highly suspicious of causing trouble in this position.

Comment: The \newpage part is just because the symbols have to be used once in order to appear in the glossary. And yes, it works fine even without the newpage command after it, the blank line ist still there..

Comment: Is `style=mcoltree` an option`? See [User Manual for glossaries.sty v4.31](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtxtLZn8_VAhXJKlAKHQCQCRQQFggrMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmirrors.ctan.org%2Fmacros%2Flatex%2Fcontrib%2Fglossaries%2Fglossaries-user.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFn4OXdsu-qJ0dWypwXtkA2nsLWnA) p.216) Section:15.1.9 In-Line Style .

Comment: The empty line is gone if I use mcoltree :) But I don't like that the entries aren't aligned anymore.. My glossary has over 50 entries and it would just be too confusing that way

Comment: The empty line is probably just a feature that is defined in the mcolalttree style. I just have no idea how to undefine it ;)

Comment: For `\glssetwidest` to be used you need \***alt**tree\*, cf. p. 213 of the User Manual.

Comment: \glssetwidest also seems to work just fine using mcol**alt**tree :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with the asterisks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems this empty line is hardcoded into the `mcolalttree` style? If you take a look at the code below, I've added in the definition for the `mcolalttree` glossary style, but with the `\mbox{}\par` commented out, and thus renamed the style `sara`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublesided,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nopostdot,acronyms]{glossaries} %,toc
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} 

% ===================
\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{sara}{%
    \setglossarystyle{alttree}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
        \begin{multicols}{2}%
            \def\@gls@prevlevel{-1}%
%           \mbox{}\par
        }%
        {\par\end{multicols}}%
}
\makeatother
% ===================

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{B}{name={$B$},description={Magnetische Flussdichte}}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},description={Magnetisierung}}
\newglossaryentry{T}{name={$T$},description={Temperatur}}
\newglossaryentry{g}{name={$g$},description={g-Faktor (Landé-Faktor)}}
\newglossaryentry{H}{name={$H$},description={Magnetische Feldstärke}}
\glssetwidest{M   }



\begin{document}
    \printnoidxglossary[type=main,style=sara,nonumberlist,title={Symbolverzeichnis}]

    \newpage
    \gls{B}, \gls{M}, \gls{T}, \gls{g}, \gls{H}

\end{document}
```

The result is as such:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a dirty workaround than a solution, however it does solve the problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nopostdot,acronyms]{glossaries} %,toc
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\newlength{\myl}

\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{B}{name={$B$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$B$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}Magnetische Flussdichte}}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$M$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}Magnetisierung}}
\newglossaryentry{T}{name={$T$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$T$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}Temperatur}}
\newglossaryentry{g}{name={$g$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$g$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}g-Faktor (Landé-Faktor)}}
\newglossaryentry{H}{name={$H$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$H$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}Magnetische Feldstärke}}

\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary[type=main,style=mcoltree,nonumberlist,title={Symbolverzeichnis}]
\newpage
\gls{B}\gls{M}\gls{T}\gls{g}\gls{H}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're happy with this, you (or I) can define a function to make the code far shorter and more readable.

Comment: First of all: thank you very much! Even though it is a bit complicated it does work for my mini-example. I tried your code with the rest of my glossary entries as well and it still works, it is just that everything looks a bit messed up now, since it contains longer entries.
`\newglossaryentry{NA}{name={$N_{\textnormal{A}}$},description={\settowidth{\myl}{$N_{\textnormal{A}}$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}Avogadro-Konstante \newline ($6,022 \cdot 10^{22}$ mol$^{-1}$)},sort=Nza}`

Comment: `\newglossaryentry{B1B2}{name={$B_1$, $B_2$},plural={$B_1$},description=\settowidth{\myl}{$B_1$, $B_2$}\hspace{-\myl}\hspace{2em}{Empirische Parameter der QTM},sort=B2}`
These are the most troubeling entries.. I'm no pro using LaTex, so could you please tell me what I need to adjust using your code in order to also fit the longer entries? Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I just changed 2em to 3em :)

Comment: Now my last problem is that the columns are not as wide as they used to be. Before the word "Empirische Parameter der QTM" fit into one row and now it is split up over two rows...

Comment: @Sara Well if you change 2em to 3em (what clearly is the right thing to do), of course there's more space needed, leaving less for the other column. I can't look into it at the moment, but maybe the manual says something about the spacing left and right of the glossary?

Comment: Even if I leave it at 2 em the line still does not fit ;)

Comment: Let's bring the dirty workarounds on: `\mbox{Empirische Parameter der QTM}` will force it into one line, but of course it will also create an overlong line which might be ugly and throw the error `Overfull \hbox in paragraph`.

Comment: I managed to fix it :) It's not optimal or anything, but for right now it''s enough. So thanks again, I appreciate your help very much!!